# Share in google plus from android application

Tags: android, google-plus, android-sharing

I have to share some text and a link from android application for that I have wrote code as follows

```
        PlusShare.Builder shareBuilder = new PlusShare.Builder(this);
        shareBuilder.setType("text/plain");
        shareBuilder.setText("text to be shared");
        shareBuilder.setContentUrl(Uri.parse("link_to_share"));
        Intent shareIntent = shareBuilder.getIntent();
        startActivityForResult(shareIntent, SHARE_GOOGLE_PLUS_REQUEST_CODE);
```

this code works fine and I can share to google plus, and am getting a call back in onActivityResult(). what my issue is if the user not installed google plus, the app stop responds and exits. how do I fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
// Google client to interact with Google API
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(ThirtyArticleDetail.this)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(ThirtyArticleDetail.this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(ThirtyArticleDetail.this).addApi(Plus.API)
    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();

btnsharegplus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    // Set sharing so that the share is started in onConnected.
                    mSignInClicked= true;

                    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                    }
                } else {
                    Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(ThirtyArticleDetail.this)
                    .setType("text/plain")
                    .setText("Welcome to the Google+ platform.")
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(articleurl))
                    //.setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/+/"))
                    .getIntent();

                    startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);
                }
            }
        });




@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,
                0).show();
        return;
    }

    if (!mIntentInProgress) {
        // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
        mConnectionResult = result;

        if (mSignInClicked) {
            // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
            // resolve all
            // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
            resolveSignInError();


        }
    }
}



@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mSignInClicked = false;
    // Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
    .setType("text/plain")
    .setText("Welcome to the Google+ platform.")
    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(articleurl))
    //.setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.google.com/+/"))
    .getIntent();

    startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 0);


}



@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    //mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}



@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}



@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(!(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()))   
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
/**
 * Sign-in into google
 * */
/*private void signInWithGplus() {
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
        mSignInClicked = true;
        resolveSignInError();
    }
}
 */
/**
 * Method to resolve any signin errors
 * */
private void resolveSignInError() {
    try {
        if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {

            mIntentInProgress = true;
            mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
        }
    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
        mIntentInProgress = false;
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        mIntentInProgress = false;
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

}
```

First of all please go through the follwing links and understand what **GoogleApiClient** actually is:

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/

https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/

**EDIT**

Dont forget to take the following **permissions** in **manifest.xml:**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

Comment: mGoogleApiClient ? how do I initialize that

Comment: I have tried your code, but it calls onConnectionFailure(), and gets an error message, sign in failed, Error signing in the specified method, please choose a different account. what is that ?

Comment: but this is for logining right ? do i need to implement all these for sharing ?

Comment: not necessary,but i have accomplished sharing through the above code